# Flippant vs Glib

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I've struggled to find much help, on the internet, for this question. I've seen flippant explained as glib, and vice versa, but I'm not sure if there's a meaningful difference between the two. My guess would be that one contains a feint indication of cruelty but - even while writing this - I've changed my mind as to which that might be!

Comment: A "glib answer" strikes me as a prepared answer, designed to divert, a bit oily; an answer that is quickly given because they have prepared for precisely your question. A "flippant answer" strikes me as offhand, thoughtless; someone answering quickly and dismissively with the first thing that comes to mind, possibly sarcastic.

Comment: You should provide dictionary definitions to indicate the research that you've done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although these words do overlap in meaning, there are differences. [Wikidiff](https://wikidiff.com/glib/flippant#:%7E:text=As%20adjectives%20the%20difference%20between,speaking%20with%20ease%20and%20rapidity.) (reformatted) brings these out fairly well:

> **flippant** [adjective]
>
> - (archaic) glib; speaking with ease and rapidity: [Barrow] *It becometh good men, in such cases, to be flippant and free in their
>   speech.*
> - nimble; limber.
> - Showing disrespect through a casual attitude, levity, and a lack of due seriousness; pert: [Burke] *a sort of flippant , vain discourse*
>   //  [2000, Anthony Howard and Jason Cowley, Decline and Fall, New
>   Statesman] *In the mid-1950s we both wrote for the same weekly, where
>   her contributions were a good deal more serious and less flippant than
>   mine.*  // [2004, *The Easy Way to Stop Smoking*]: *Our society treats
>   smoking flippantly as a slightly distasteful habit that can injure
>   your health. It is not. It is drug addiction.*
>
> .....................
>
> **glib** [adjective]
>
> - Having a ready flow of words but lacking thought or understanding; superficial; shallow.
> - Smooth or slippery: *a sheet of glib ice*
> - Artfully persuasive in nature: *a glib tongue*; *a glib speech*
>
> ...

However, obviously, the senses are not listed in order of modern idiomaticity.

I'd say the default meaning of **flippant** is the third listed here,

- *speaking with levity  and a lack of due seriousness, and thus showing disrespect and a casual attitude*

whereas the default meaning of **glib** is again the third, but informed by the others:

- *artfully [cleverly / skilfully, especially in a crafty / cunning / slippery way] persuasive, having a ready flow of words*

Comment: Lovely detail, thank you.